# Force empty table cell to exist

Tags: html, css

I am using a table to display code, along with some CSS magic:

```css
* { tab-size: 4; }
body { background-color: lightsteelblue; }
table, tr, td {
 text-align: left;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: none;
}
table {
 font-family: "Courier New";
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 3px solid black;
 padding: 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 counter-reset: linenumbers;
 background-color: white;
}
table tr td:last-child {
 white-space: pre;
 display: block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: black;
}
table tr td:first-child {
 text-align: right;
 background-color: black;
}
table tr td:first-child:before {
 user-select: none;
 display: inline-block;
 counter-increment: linenumbers;
 content: counter(linenumbers);
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 margin: 0px;
 max-width: none;
}
table tr:hover td:last-child {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 0;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td>#include &lt;iostream&gt;</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>int main()</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>{</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>&#9;std::cout &lt;&lt; "Hello, world!" &lt;&lt; std::endl;</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>}</td></tr>
</table>
```

The issue is that the second line, line 2, displays but does not get copied when you select all the code and copy-paste it. It also does not change its background color when you hover over it. How can I force it to exist *without putting content in it*? When copied and pasted into a plain-text editor such as notepad, the blank line needs to be preserved, and it needs to be blank. No zero-width-joiner trickery that could trip up compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML entity `&NewLine;` which is the character "new line" (`\n`) and that will be copy pasted. No character cannot be "copied". Alternatively you can use `&nbsp;` but that will add an extra space.

As a side note, you could have a look at CodeMirror so you don't need to reinvent the wheel (but maybe that's as an exercice or you could have any good reason, just saying.)

```css
* { tab-size: 4; }
body { background-color: lightsteelblue; }
table, tr, td {
 text-align: left;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: none;
}
table {
 font-family: "Courier New";
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 3px solid black;
 padding: 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 counter-reset: linenumbers;
 background-color: white;
}
table tr td:last-child {
 white-space: pre;
 display: block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: black;
}
table tr td:first-child {
 text-align: right;
 background-color: black;
}
table tr td:first-child:before {
 user-select: none;
 display: inline-block;
 counter-increment: linenumbers;
 content: counter(linenumbers);
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 margin: 0px;
 max-width: none;
}
table tr:hover td:last-child {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
 border-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 0;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td>#include &lt;iostream&gt;</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>&NewLine;</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>int main()</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>{</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>&#9;std::cout &lt;&lt; "Hello, world!" &lt;&lt; std::endl;</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `table tr td:last-child:empty:after { content: "\A"; }`